# Not exists/Where NOT in

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Doing a pie chart in crystal. Items are

- Inquiries
- Referrals
- Followups

A referral has to have an inquiry, A followup has to have a referral.

I want to show pie chart of referrals to inquiries so the slice would be the referred count, the rest of the pie would be the non-referred inquires.

Table A:

```
customer001 INQ 1/1/2013  
customer001 INQ 9/30/2013.  
customer001 REF 10/15/2013.    
customer001 FOL 10/30/2013.
```

This customer has 4 records. First off I will ignore the followup record in my crystal reports record filter.

That leaves:

```
customer001 INQ 1/1/2013  
customer001 INQ 9/30/2013  
customer001 REF 10/15/2013
```

Now when I run my chart the pie will show 2 INQ's and 1 REF in the pie chart.
But I want it to be a 50/50 pie, because the INQ record that is most recent belongs to the REF record of 10/15.

I need a SQL statement that removes the 9/30/2013 record out of a view.
I have written code (Top(1) MAX of the date field in a view that gives me this output with the most recent INQ record inserted to the end of all records. Now I need a second statement that strips the duplicate record out.

```
ID---------Code--Date----INQcode---INQdate  
customer001 INQ 1/1/2013 INQ 9/30/2013   
customer001 INQ 9/30/2013 INQ 9/30/2013  
customer001 REF 10/15/2013 INQ 9/30/2013.
```

So in my second unwritten view I need to write out only the records `where code<> INQcode AND Date<>INQdate`

Comment: If a REF has to have a INQ then why don't you do `COUNT(REF)` for the referred count and `COUNT(INQ) - COUNT(REF)` for the non-referred count?

Comment: the population =2. 1 "occurance" is an inq/ref occasion, the other occasion is an INQ only occasion. a pie chart would look like one-third slice, but in reality it is a one-half slice

Comment: How do you know that the REF record belongs to the INQ record? Just because they are adjacent? Because their clustered indices are sequential? Along that line, is a REF to be ignored *always* when its clustered index is next after an INQ? Is there only one INQ permitted per date per Customer?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ROW_NUMBER function partitioning over "Code" and ordering by "Date" descending like the following query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS rno,
     ID,
     CODE,
     CONVERT (VARCHAR, DATE, 101) AS fdate
FROM   A
WHERE  CODE <> 'FOL'
```

you will get.

```
    RNO ID           CODE       FDATE
    1   customer001  INQ        09/30/2013
    2   customer001  INQ        01/01/2013
    1   customer001  REF        10/15/2013
```

Then if you use a left outer join using that same select statement on RNO where the code of the right table is 'REF' like below

```
SELECT a1.ID,
   a1.CODE AS Code1,
   a2.CODE AS Code2,
   a1.fdate AS fdate1,
   a2.fdate AS fdate2
FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS rno,
     ID,
     CODE,
     CONVERT (VARCHAR, DATE, 101) AS fdate
  FROM A
  WHERE CODE <> 'FOL'
) AS a1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS rno,
     ID,
     CODE,
     CONVERT (VARCHAR, DATE, 101) AS fdate
  FROM   A
  WHERE  CODE <> 'FOL'
  ) AS a2
  ON a1.rno = a2.rno
  AND a2.CODE = 'REF'
  WHERE  a1.CODE <> 'REF'
  ORDER BY FDATE1
```

and finally use a where clause filter on the left table where code is not equal to 'REF' you will get the following.

```
    ID          CODE1   CODE2   FDATE1      FDATE2
    customer001 INQ     (null)  01/01/2013  (null)
    customer001 INQ     REF     09/30/2013  10/15/2013
```

Hope this helps or is what you are looking for.